# C# Transparent form, click through but make exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a form which is transparent and "unclickable", the click go "through the form"
However this form has a 20 pixel red border which i want to be able to click so my question is can i somehow make an exception to detect the click on border.

1. Make transparent

```
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

            this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
```

2. Make clicks go through

```
             int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
             SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
            // Create and add the custom border control to the form
```

3. Border

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            // Draw a red border around the form
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 20))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
            }
        }
```

I tried something like this, am i looking the right direction ?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    const int HTTRANSPARENT = -1;
    const int HTCLIENT = 1;

    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left && !isClickThrough)
        {
            // Set the window style to make it click-through
            int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
            SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
            isClickThrough = true;
        }
        else if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None && isClickThrough)
        {
            // Reset the window style to make it non-click-through
            int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
            SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle & ~0x80000 & ~0x20);
            isClickThrough = false;
        }

        m.Result = (IntPtr)(isClickThrough ? HTTRANSPARENT : HTCLIENT);
        return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Another solution would be if i knew how to caputure mousevents when using SetWindowLong

Comment: You fell victim to an old Windows bug, been around too long to fix.  Color.Turquoise was a very unlucky choice, pick Color.Fuchsia and you won't need any of this code.

Comment: Hans I just found this out myself while you answering this. So i can simply write this off as a windows bug ? lol 3 hours wasted. But thank you Hans !

Comment: Same is case with Red also this problem not only turquoise, some colors work some now very weird. is there some information about this around as you know ?

Comment: Yes, red misbehaves the same way.  I haven't seen a pattern to the color value, Color.Fuchsia has been the traditional choice for color-keying for a very long time and still works well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my own question is instead of using :

```
         int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
         SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
```

If i set the backcolor to magenta instead of turquoise, it's clickthrough while other elements like border or buttons still are clickable. With turquose this was not the case.

```
        this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
```

The trick works for some colors, for example if you use Color.Turquose it will be transparent but handles clicks, but using Magenta the form will be mouse transparent too.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people